# std class specialization - meeting the standard library requirements for the original std::array template

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization, stdarray

In [Is it safe to define a specialization for std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74868066/is-it-safe-to-define-a-specialization-for-stdarray) the questioner asks if it's safe to specialize `std::array` for a program defined type which has an *expensive* default constructor. The goal is to instead initialize all elements in the `std::array` by using a *cheap* constructor instead of the default constructor.

I'm not questioning that design at this point. I'm curious about the possibilities and, to that problem, I suggested to make use of brace elision on initialization of aggregates, define an inner class and use a special constructor via a tag:

```cpp
namespace foo {
struct cheap_tag_t {};
inline constexpr cheap_tag_t cheap_tag;

class bar {
public:
    inline bar() { std::cout << "expensive ctor\n"; }
    inline bar(int) { std::cout << "int ctor\n"; }
    inline bar(cheap_tag_t) { std::cout << "cheap ctor\n"; }
};
}  // namespace foo
```

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
    requires (N != 0)     // let the standard array take care of N==0
struct std::array<foo::bar, N> {
    struct inner_array {
        foo::bar data[N];
    };

    inner_array m_data{
        []<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) -> inner_array {
            return {(void(I), foo::cheap_tag)...};
        }(std::make_index_sequence<N>())
    };

    // ... fully compliant member functions ...
};
```

I can't find anything in the standard prohibiting this odd specialization. I say it's odd because it has an, to an end user, unexpected feature shown last below:

```cpp
std::array<foo::bar, 0> b0;    // not using the specialization at all
std::array<foo::bar, 2> b1;    // cheap ctor
std::array<foo::bar, 2> b2{};  // cheap ctor
std::array<foo::bar, 2> b3{1}; // one "int ctor" + one "expensive ctor" (surprised user)
```

To the language lawyering question:

- Given that the rest of the specialization will meet the standard library requirements for the original `std::array` template, does the above part of the specialization agree with *the standard*<sup>1, 2</sup>?

---

<sup>1. "the standard" I've (tried to) read is the C++23 draft. [`namespace.std/2`](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#2)</sup>

> Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace `std` provided that
> **(a)** the added declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and
> **(b)** the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

<sup>If there's a different answer to my question in an earlier, or future, standard that you know of, feel free to mention it. It's not required to get an accepted answer.</sup>

<sup>2. If the above part of the specialization is ok according to "the standard", but you see other problems ahead making it hard/impossible to fulfill the requirements, please feel free to mention those as well. Again, not required.</sup>

Comment: "*by using a cheap constructor*" Define "cheap". It's *never* going to be faster than aggregate initialization, since that has the power to simply use the initializing expressions to directly initialize the members. Constructors require the creation of arguments, which can be copied/moved into the members.

Comment: @NicolBolas  The default and "cheap" constructors are those in the class for which the `std::array` is specialized. The `std::array` will be aggregate initialized for sure, by a `cheap_tag_t`, or via an initializer list or by `default` (which the OP tries to avoid).

Comment: My suggestion would be to make the expensive constructor take a `expensive_tag_t` parameter instead

Comment: Not sure, might be that the example takes too much space and distracts from the actual question whether it is allowed to specialize at all. The important bits are in a footnote

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, that would probably be the wise choice. I stuck with what was presented in [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74868066/is-defining-a-specialization-for-stdarray-allowed-will-it-result-in-undefined) and got interested in if this would meet the requirements.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number At the time I wrote the question I was very interested in if the parts I presented (my solution to the original problem) would in it self _"meet the standard library requirements"_, so I put much focus on those parts.

Comment: This is what happens when people do not embrace Partially formed objects. https://youtu.be/HcSAIZafNZU?feature=shared

Comment: @alfC That seems like an interesting video, but it's rather long. Is there a certain point in it that is directly applicable to my case so I can jump directly there?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, there is a shorter version of the video (~40min) with the same title.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OQKZl7ha7g . To be honest, it really does take a lot to understand the deep reasons for this; otherwise, if you are not interested in the reasoning, you can take it by faith. The short version in your case is: if you have a constructor that is cheaper than the default constructor, that should be the default constructor, even if it leaves the object in a partially formed state (i.e. only usable after assignment).

Comment: @alfC Aha, yes. The situation I tried to provide a solution for should be avoided, I agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your specialization cannot be used in the following way:

```
struct anyconv {
    template<typename T>
    operator T() { return T(); }
};

std::array<foo::bar, 2> x = {anyconv{}, anyconv{}};
```

However, `anyconv` is implicitly convertible to `foo::bar` and so by the requirement in [[array.overview]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/array.overview#2) it should be possible to list-initialize `std::array<foo::bar, 2>` with 2 initializer-clauses that are of type `anyconv`.

Comment: I'm not 100% - what in C++ would my idea be violating? I  worked it out of an idea that "anything goes" - as long as you fultill these pretty hard things to fulfill ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo As you quote in the question "_provided that [...] the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template_". One of these requirements is [array.overview]/2 which requires that my usage example ought to be well-formed, but it isn't with your partial specialization because the first `anyconv{}` can and will initialize the whole `inner_array`, leaving nothing for the second `anyconv{}` to initialize.

Comment: Yes, I now see what you mean. `anyconv` converts to `inner_array<T>` instead of `T`. Bummer, but I'll have to accept it. Thanks!