# Defining a conversion function for a template specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The following excerpt is from [pages 686-687](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA686&lpg=PA686&dq=%22there+is+one+kind+of+combination+of+object%22&source=bl&ots=oh1Hc_pkeP&sig=ACfU3U0LqGcZCzZiUx4o5WPz9ryABaiX0A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig2rGZ_I3_AhWDhVYBHfRHDosQ6AF6BAgREAM#v=onepage&q=%22there%20is%20one%20kind%20of%20combination%20of%20object%22&f=false) of *Programming: Principles and Practice* by Bjarne Stroustrup:

> **19.3.4 Containers and inheritance**
>
> There is one kind of combination of object-oriented programming and generic programming that people always try, but it doesn’t work: attempting to use a container of objects of a derived class as a container of objects of a base class. For example:
>
> ```
> vector<Shape> vs;
> vector<Circle> vc;
>
> vs = vc;                // error: vector<Shape> required
>
> void f(vector<Shape>&);
> f(vc);                  // error: vector<Shape> required
> ```
>
> But why not? After all, you say, I can convert a Circle to a Shape! Actually, no, you can’t. You can convert a Circle* to a Shape* and a Circle& to a Shape&, but we deliberately disabled assignment of Shapes, so that you wouldn’t have to wonder what would happen if you put a Circle with a radius into a Shape variable that doesn’t have a radius (§14.2.4). What would have happened — had we allowed it — would have been what is called “slicing” and is the class object equivalent of integer truncation (§3.9.2).

I'm not sure I understand why `vs = vc` is an error. The annotation says `// error: vector<Shape> required`. I tried the following toy example:

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"

class B {
    
};

class D : public B {
    int x;

public:
    D() {
        x = 7;
    }
};

class D2 : B {
    
};

// vector<D>& vector<D>::vector<B>() {
//     return vector<B>;
// }

int main() {

    vector<B> vb;
    vector<D> vd;
    
    vb = vd;

    return 0;

}
```

When I attempt to compile it, the error message I get reads:

> test.cpp:35:11: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Vector' and `Vector<D>`)
> 35 |    vd2 = vd;
> |          ^~
> In file included from test.cpp:1:
> ../std_lib_facilities.h:70:27: note: candidate: 'Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector&)'
> 70 |    template< class T> struct Vector : public std::vector
> |                              ^~~~~~
> ../std_lib_facilities.h:70:27: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Vector' to 'const Vector&'
> ../std_lib_facilities.h:70:27: note: candidate: 'Vector& Vector::operator=(Vector&&)'
> ../std_lib_facilities.h:70:27: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Vector' to 'Vector&&'

So, it seems that it's not so much that a `vector<Shape>` is required, but rather that `vector<Shape>` does not have an assignment operator that takes a `vector<Circle>` as input, and `vector<Circle>` does not have the conversion function `vector<Shape>()`. **Is this correct?**

This also got me thinking about whether it would be possible to supply a conversion function for the `vector<D>` specialisation myself, but when I try to define `vector<D>& vector<D>::vector<B>()`, I get the following error:

> test.cpp:22:10: error: specializing member 'Vector::operator=' requires 'template<>' syntax
> 22 |  vector& vector::vector() {
> |           ^

I'm not sure how to write it in template syntax, or if it is even possible to do so. I don't quite see the problem with being able to augment a specialisation with our own member functions. In the last paragraph of the section, Stroustrup says:

> Inheritance is a powerful and subtle mechanism and templates do not implicitly extend its reach. [..] Just remember that "`D` is a `B`" does not imply "`C<D>` is a `C<B>`" for an arbitrary template `C`.

So, "`D` is a `B`" does not imply "`C<D>` is a `C<B>`", but that doesn't mean that both can't be true at the same time. **So, why wasn't I able to define the conversion function?**

Comment: you cannot provide a conversion for `std::vector<Foo>` in a portable way.

Comment: just wording, but there is no contradiction between "a vector<Shape> is required" and "vector<Shape> does not have an assignment operator that takes a vector<Circle> as input, and vector<Circle> does not have the conversion function vector<Shape>()". The latter is the reason for the former being true. " it's not so much..." -> it is very much about that

Comment: You can provide your own slicing conversion function.  Slicing conversion functions are of limited usefulness (in general).  They may be useful in rare cases in a specific context.  Or for example, change `vb = vd;` to `vb = vector<B>(vd.begin(), vd.end());` which is basically what you'd be doing in a slicing conversion function.

Comment: @Eljay: You don't even need to move from a temporary `vector<Base>`, you can do it in-place using `.assign(begin_iterator, end_iterator)`

Comment: Thank you 463035818_is_not_a_number and Ted Lyngmo for your answers, I have upvoted both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion it is unfortunate that the book conflates two issues. They are very much related, but each on its own would deserve an in depth explanation.

One is that `std::vector<A>` can't be converted to `std::vector<B>` even though `A` can be converted to `B`. `std::vector` simply does not provide the conversion.

The other issue is that when you are using inheritance then most of the time a `std::vector<base>` is a bad idea. For this I refer you to [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

---

Further note that the book is talking about `std::vector` specifically. There is nothing that prevents you to provide a conversion from `foo<A>` to `foo<B>` when `A` can be converted to `B` (see below). And the standard library does that sometimes. For example a `shared_ptr<T>` can be constructed from a `Y*` when `Y*` can be converted to a `T*` (see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). Also `std::pair` has implicit conversions enabled, for example the following compiles:

```
 std::pair<int,int> x;
 std::pair<double,double> y;
 x = y;
```

For why this works see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair.

---

`std::vector` does not have such conversions and you cannot easily add them. You cannot add members to `std::vector` neither are you allowed to add specializations for `std::vector<my_type>`. Consider that implicit conversions often do more harm than good, because they potentially hide bugs:

```
void foo(const std::vector<A>&);
void bar(const std::vector<B>&);

std::vector<A> a;
bar(a);           // ups, typo, but would compile if conversions would be available
```

It is common to make conversions explicit and only enable implicit conversions when their use is natural and desired (as for example with `shared_ptr` its natural, because its just what raw pointers do as well).

On the other hand, nothing forbids you to write a function to make the conversion explicit:

```
std::vector<B> convert(const std::vector<A>&);

bar( convert(a) );  // explicit is good!
```

---

> So, "D is a B" does not imply "C is a C", but that doesn't mean that both can't be true at the same time. So, why wasn't I able to define the conversion function?

You should not define the conversion for `std::vector`. You can do it for your own template:

```
struct A {};
struct B {
    operator A() const { return {}; }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo {
    T t;

    template <typename U>
    operator foo<U>() const {
        return {static_cast<U>(t)};
    }
};

int main() {
    foo<A> fa;
    foo<B> fb;
    fa = fb;   // uses implicit conversion 
    //fb = fa; // error 
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oTf7Mns54)

However, this is just a contrived example. In reality you almost always want the conversion operators to be `explicit`.

Comment: Thank you, @463035818_is_not_a_number. You mention: "...neither are you allowed to add specializations for `std::vector<my_type>`." I'm not sure what this means. If we can create a template for `std::vector<my_type>` (as is shown in the first code snippet of Ted's answer), then wouldn't instantiating that template create a specialisation for `std::vector<my_type>`?

Comment: @user51462 we are not sure if it is allowed what Ted shows in the answer. However, the thing about specializing `std::vector<D>` in the answer is only for illustration. The crucial point is that it would reuquire a lot of work, it requires so much work that whether it is allowed or not is kind of secondary. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880400/std-class-specialization-meeting-the-standard-library-requirements-for-the-ori

Comment: I see, I figured that since it compiled, it would be ok. But I'm guessing there's more to it that I don't fully understand right now. Thank you @463035818_is_not_a_number.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this correct?

Yes, the two distinct types `vector<Shape>` and `vector<Circle>` can't be implicitly converted into eachother.

> So, why wasn't I able to define the conversion function?

You didn't show us what you tried, only the error.

In order to specialize `std::vector<D>` you'd need something like this:

```cpp
template<>
class std::vector<D> {
public:
    std::vector<D>& operator=(const std::vector<B>&) {
        return *this;
    }
    // all the rest of the gory std::vector implementation details
};
```

But specializing `std::vector` [may not be allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880400/std-class-specialization-meeting-the-standard-library-requirements-for-the-ori) and would require **a lot** of work so that's not going to fly.

---

You could inherit from `std::vector<D>` and add your conversion function:

```cpp
class vectorD : public std::vector<D> {
public:
    using std::vector<D>::vector;
    using std::vector<D>::operator=;

    vectorD& operator=(const std::vector<B>&) {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Note that inherting from `std::` classes is often frowned upon but there's nothing preventing you to do it and as long as you don't pass base class pointers to `vector<D>` around and expect to be able to `delete` a `vectorD` thorugh one of those, it's ususally fine.

---

A third option would be to define how to convert from `B` to `D` in `D` itself. This makes sense in most situations:

```cpp
class D : public B {
    int x = 7;

public:
    D() = default;
    D(const B&) {}      // define how to convert a B into a D
};
```

You can then simply use the `assign` member function of the `vector`:

```cpp
vd.assign(vb.begin(), vb.end());
```

Comment: afaik adding specializations to standard library templates is not allowed (unless explicitly stated, like eg for `std::hash`)

Comment: didnt find some relevant reference for `std::vector`. Though even if not allowed, imho it is worth to show, its not that tempting to actually do it anyhow

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You are correct and I meant to write that but it slipped my mind.  Added that now.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I just realized that I've actually asked if it's allowed myself but that question is still unanswered. :-) I'm thinking that it actually is allowed because the standard says: _"Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace `std` provided that..."_ - but I've left it open for the more language-lawyer savvy to answer.

Comment: do you have a link to the question?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yeah, I put that in the answer too. It's about `std::array` but I suspect the same goes for `std::vector`.